# JavaScript-- Array Variable getting Updated Automatically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was writing code for shopping cart function. When ever I add a product to cart, for each product, at first time and additional attribute called quantity gets added.

This is my code:

```
myStoreCartService.factory('Cart',function() {
    var userCart = [];
    var cartSummary = [];

    var cartConsolidatedData = [];
    var currentTotalMaster;

    function formCart() {
        cartConsolidatedData = [];
        var dup = false;
        var temp;

        for(x in userCart) {
            dup = false;  

            for(z in cartConsolidatedData) {
                if(cartConsolidatedData[z].productname == userCart[x].productname) {
                    cartConsolidatedData[z].quantity = cartConsolidatedData[z].quantity + 1;
                    dup = true;
                    break;
                }
            }     

            if(!dup) {
                // temp = userCart[x];
                // temp.quantity = 1;
                cartConsolidatedData.push(userCart[x]);

                for(y in cartConsolidatedData) {
                    if(cartConsolidatedData[y].productname == userCart[x].productname) {
                        cartConsolidatedData[y].quantity = 1;
                        break;
                    }
                } 
            } 
        }        
    };

    return {
        addItemToCart: function(cartData) {
            console.log(cartData);
            userCart.push(cartData); 
            formCart(); 
        },  
        retrieveCart: function() {
            return userCart;
        }
    });
```

Here even the fist item in userCart variable get quantity attribute, however just cartConsolidatedData variable's values should have got the this attribute.

I am stuck bad time here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand your code but I suppose cartData is an object and you push that object to userCart like this

```
userCart.push(cartData);
```

then you push the same object to cartConsolidatedData with this command

```
cartConsolidatedData.push(userCart[x]);
```

So when you do this:

```
cartConsolidatedData[y].quantity=1;
```

You are adding a property to the cartData object and not as you state to the cartConsolidatedData array. Because cartConsolidatedData[y] is a cartData object and since it's a reference it means any change you do to it will also be reflected in the userCart array that points to the same cartData.